# Buggy in 1 variation of program to find height of binary search tree

Tags: c, data-structures, binary-search-tree

This implementation to find height of a BST works:

```
int findHeight1(treeNode_type*root)
{
  if(root==NULL)
      return -1;
   else
   {
      return max(findHeight1(root->left),findHeight1(root->right))+1;
   }
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
int findHeight(treeNode_type*root)
{
   if( root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL)//current node on stack frame is leaf node
      return 0;
   else
   {
      return max(findHeight(root->left),findHeight(root->right))+1;
   }
}
```

Both implementations' base case logic seems sound to me but why doesn't the latter work.

Trivial,but just in case:

```
typedef struct treeNode_type treeNode_type;

struct treeNode_type
{
   int data;
   treeNode_type *left;
   treeNode_type *right;
};
```

Comment: In the second case, when the node is a leaf node, the height of the tree is `1`, not `0`.  Also, the second case doesn't seem to handle the scenario where the left pointer is not null but the right isn't, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring comment to answer.*</sup>

In the second case, when the node is a leaf node, the height of the tree is 1, not 0. Also, the second case doesn't seem to handle the scenario where the left pointer is not null but the right isn't, or vice versa.

You could use:

```
int findHeight(treeNode_type*root)
{
   if (root == NULL)
      return 0;
   else if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
      return 1;
   else
   {
      return max(findHeight(root->left), findHeight(root->right)) + 1;
   }
}
```

It's not clear there's a significant benefit compared to the simpler first version of the code, though this does avoid two recursive calls for leaf nodes.   You could add these conditions and tests before the `else` clause:

```
   else if (root->left == NULL)
      return findHeight(root->right) + 1;
   else if (root->right == NULL)
      return findHeight(root->left) + 1;
```

Again, it isn't clear that it will speed up the processing significantly; the extra conditions might even stall the CPU pipeline and slow it down.

Comment: I'm not sure why the second case has to  handle the scenario where the left pointer is not null but the right isn't, or vice versa since I only want to test if node at a stack frame is leaf node or not. `(root == NULL)` is just 1 stack frame after `(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)`.  So if  `(root == NULL)` returns `-1`(which I wrote in the question) shouldn't `(root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) //ie a leaf node` return 0 since its 1 stack frame before `(root == NULL)`? So your answer is returning 1 more than the actual height(my understanding is probably flawed)

Comment: You don't have to handle the asymmetric left vs right pointers; you can leave the line that returns the `max + 1` in place — as the code shows.  I said "you _could_ add" which means you also "you _could_ leave them out".  I also observed that there's unlikely to be a measurable benefit from adding them, and maybe even a measurable cost to doing so. And you could leave out the `else if` line, but then you're back to the 'known to work' version 1 you started with.  There are quite a lot ways you can do it; some of them work — and the three or four variants just outlined all work. (Others don't!)